# how to select some value from multiple table in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I want to to select some students from table A where students username and class code are not inside table B. So it will show all student that not inside the student class list yet.

the query was like

```
SELECT students from TableA WHERE username NOT IN tableB AND classcode = CODE
```

**models.py**

```
class modelStudentclassss m(models.Model):
    classcode = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
```

```
class modelUser(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
```

**views.py**

```
studentclass = modelStudentclass.objects.all()
studentdata = modelUser.objects.exclude(studentusername = studentclass.username).filter(role="student", classcode=classcode)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with:

```
Studentclass.objects.exclude(username__in=User.objects.values('username')).filter(
    classcode=code
)
```

---

> **Note**: Models normally have no `Model…` prefix. Therefore it might be better to rename <s>`modelUser`</s> to `User`.

---

> **Note**: Specifying [**`null=False`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null) is not necessary: fields are by default not NULLable.

---

> **Note**: Specifying [**`blank=False`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#blank) is not necessary: fields are by default not blank and thus are required by a form.

Comment: Hello, i tried this already but it's not working.
the point is i want to show student data from student model where the student is not inside student class table. the way how i check it is if student username is NOT inside the studentclass table AND classcode is class that i choose, then data will showed up.

For example:
Student A is a Math student
Student B is a Music student
Student C is a Physics student

then i want to add B & C into math class. how to do it?

User model has username (doesn't have classcode field)
Classmodel has classcode & username

Sorry for bother you :)

Comment: i tried this also

User.objects.exclude(username__in = studentClass.objects.values('username')).filter(role="siswa")

but it only show student that not inside any class. (Not inside table)

Comment: @AlbertWijaya: but `User` has no `classcode` field...

Comment: oh .. i think i solved it already by using this
User.objects.exclude(username__in = studentClass.objects.values('username').filter(classcode=code)).filter(role="siswa")

Thanks for your reply and help tho .. and Thanks for the note! God Bless!